# Does not name a type error for c++ namespace

Tags: c++, namespaces, c++17

So I was building a C++ program and I have no idea how to solve this namespace issue. I am running on C++17 so there shouldn't be an issue with nested namespaces. I keep getting the error on line 3 in the `.cpp` file.

This is the `.h` file:

```
#include <memory>
#include "Entity.h"

namespace Hearthstonerepl::Action
{
    class Playcard
    {
    private:
        std::unique_ptr<Entity> card;

    public:
        Playcard(std::unique_ptr<Entity>& Card);
        ~Playcard() = default;
    };
}
```

And this is the `.cpp` file:

```
#include "Playcard.h"

namespace Hearthstonerepl::Action // error: expected ‘{’ before ‘::’ token
                                  //‘Action’ in namespace ‘::’ does not name a type
{
    Playcard::Playcard(std::unique_ptr<Entity>& Card)
    {
        card = std::move(Card);
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Could it be your compiler doesn't fully support C++17? What compiler and version is it?

Comment: Which compiler + version? How do you compile?

Comment: I use an IDE so, it has an internal compiler, which I guess is GCC/G++ 5.4.1  could this be an issue??

Comment: Nested namespace shows up in GCC 6: https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx-status.html#cxx17

Comment: Oh I see. so even though I changed my setting to c++17, the version doesn't follow up all the supports. Thanks!

Comment: Looking the support matrix over, it looks like if you want full C++ 17, you should see if you can force the compiler up to at least 7, though I have no idea how easy that will be to do with the IDE you are using. Could be as easy and install it and change a few options in the IDE. Might be a worthwhile question in how to do this, but it's probably better suited to a help request to the IDEs makers.

Comment: @user4581301 well it's a online cloud IDE, so not sure if I can use different compilers.

Comment: You get a compiler error in the cpp file but not in the h file that you include? Can you please provide a one file [mcve]!?